# Using jQuery to load images, how to stop caching

Tags: jquery, image, caching, load, attr

I'm using jQuery to load an image dynamically on a web page. Every time a user hits submit on the page a new image is generated. The problem is, unless I append a random number at the end of the image URL, the same image is returned due to caching.

My code looks like this...

```
img.attr('src', url + resp.id + '.png?' + cache);
```

I would like to get rid of the cache string at the end and still serve a fresh image, anyone know how to do this? I don't believe it is a problem on the HTTP server side (using nginx), since making a direct request shows the correct image even without the cache buster.

Comment: You should check the headers your server sends along with the image~ what kind of cache-control etc.

Answer (score 3):

That's the simplest way you can circumvent this issue, cause it's there by design.

The normal thing to do is appending the time in the string

```
var d = new Date();
var cache = d.getTime(); 

// getTime() Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
```